# LIKE when using NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC and NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-like

Oracle Version: 11.2.0.2.0

I have set `NLS_COMP = 'LINGUISTIC'` and `NLS_SORT = 'BINARY_CI'`.

Whenever I use a `LIKE` comparison without a leading wildcard (%), it does not return the correct results.
Here is a generic example. My problem is obviously with Query #3. Anyone experienced this before?

```
CREATE TABLE People     
(      
  ID NUMBER(1,0),    
  FirstName NVARCHAR2(20),    
  LastName NVARCHAR2(20)
);    

INSERT INTO People (ID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('1', 'John', 'Doe');    
INSERT INTO People (ID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('2', 'Jane', 'Doe');    
INSERT INTO People (ID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('3', 'Rich', 'Donner');    
INSERT INTO People (ID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('4', 'Mike', 'Redoer');            

-- Query #1    
SELECT ID FROM People WHERE Lastname = 'doe';

-- Results (Correct)    
-- 1    
-- 2


-- Query #2    
SELECT ID FROM People WHERE Lastname LIKE '%doe%';

-- Results (Correct)    
-- 1    
-- 2    
-- 4


-- Query #3
SELECT ID FROM People WHERE Lastname LIKE 'do%';

-- Results (Incorrect)    
-- 1    
-- 2    
-- 3    
-- 4
```

Comment: This certainly looks like a bug in the LIKE operator when BINARY_CI is specified.  Try searching metalink, and if you don't find anything related submit an SR to Oracle.

Comment: actually this scenario only happens in the above mentioned version of oracle, but in Oracle 10g r2 LIKE operator works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Query 3 gives you this because do% is saying : find me anyone whose last name contains 0 or more character after the string 'do' ( that why you also get Redoer there..)

what result where you expecting from Q3 ?

**Update**

if you just want starting just by 'do'
you could try

```
LIKE '[d]o%';
```

**Update 2**

After further [reading](http://www.orafaq.com/node/999)/testing here is what i found ,for what you want to do(finding any thing starting by 'do'), you don't really need  NLS_SORT='BINARY_CI' since this one does set the sort to case insensitive and we lose the advantage of having the first letter in Caps and the search get screwed up there.
So assuming that the first letter is in Cap all you need to do is :

```
alter session set nls_comp='LINGUISTIC';  
SELECT ID FROM People WHERE Lastname LIKE 'Do%';

ID
1
2
3
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/999fb/39) is the test i did, I hope that helps :)

Comment: Yes, But start with 'do' not 'Redo'.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct.  As far as I'm aware "do%" means "find me all strings which begin with 'do' and have zero or more characters following".  If the last names are all changed to lower case and NLS_SORT is set back to BINARY then Q3 returns the expected values (1, 2, 3).  See the [Oracle docs for Pattern-matching Conditions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions007.htm) - see the section titled "LIKE Condition: General Examples".  It appears that setting NLS_SORT to BINARY_CI is breaking this somehow, or the docs are misleading/incomplete.

Comment: What you posted in your update makes no sense in terms of SQL's `LIKE` operator (unless you're actually looking for '[' followed by 'd' followed by 'o' followed by ']'). It appears you're conflating regular expressions and the limited wildcarding supported by the `LIKE` operator.  Per Oracle's documentations, brackets ('[' and ']') have no effect in a `LIKE` comparison unless you use them as an escape character.  I suggest you [read the fine manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions007.htm) and test before you post.

Comment: Had you had tested what you posted you would have immediately found it returned no results. Please consider editing your post to remove the misleading material.

Comment: actually brackets in LIKE define a charater list and [d]o% is just and ugly way of doing 'do%' (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)